# How to mathematically check if it is possible to add $n$ numbers to make any number between $1$ and $N$?

Tags: number-theory

I was checking the question:

> Which $5$ numbers can make any number between $1$ and $31$?

And I found the answer by starting from the smallest number that is required i.e. $1$ and then trying to check every number if it is required or if it can be made from other numbers, till I reach a certain high value as follows:

$1$
$2$
$3 = 2+1$
$4$
$5 = 4+1$
$6 = 4+2$
$7 = 4+2+1$
$8$
$9 = 8+1$
$10 = 8+2$
$11 = 8+2+1$
$12 = 8+4$
$13 = 8+4+1$
$14 = 8+4+2$
$15 = 8+4+2+1$
$16$

And so on.

I found this answer online to do binary representation of $5$ bits. But it doesn't make sense. How do we know that the numbers will only be in the powers of two? I see similar results can be achieved for numbers $1, 3, 7, 15, 63, 127$ and so on...so, is this possible only to these numbers and how can we conclude that without checking each permutation?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Using only the operation of addition one can construct any non-zero natural number from just the unit $1$. Can you be more precise about what you mean by "make a number"?

Comment: All the n numbers should be different and hence, we can't use 1 more than once. And it needs to be an addition only. The practical application is you can create objects with these n numbers and use them to reach any required value...like we have 1, 2, 5 and 10 pennys

Comment: I think I should rephrase as my question to "How to findout the minimum unique numbers to make a given number through addition only"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the fact that every number has a unique representation in base $2$.

Now, there are $5$ bits and numbers range from $1$ to $31$.

Example:
$19$ in binary is $10011$ which means $19=1+2+16$.

You can also use this:
$$31=1+b+b^2+b^3+b^4$$

$b=2$

Comment: I think you need to specify exactly what you mean by that first sentence. Every number has a unique representation in *any* base - if it doesn't, it's not a number system! Base 2 is not unique in this regard.

Comment: It was just an emphasis on base $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if you have a set of $k$ numbers to use, then there are $2^k$ different [subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) you can sum. If all these sums are different consecutive numbers, you'll get the sums $0$ through $2^k-1$. You can't do better than this with only $k$ numbers, because there aren't enough subsets. The powers-of-two strategy achieves this best case (because binary representations are unique), so it's optimal.

If $n$ is not a power of two, there may be other sets that give you the sums $0$ through $n-1$, but any such set must have size at least $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$ by the counting argument above, so it's no better than the binary strategy.